# Jquery validate function error object can not be parsed in ie8

Tags: jquery, json, validation, internet-explorer-8

```
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.next().attr("id") == "errordiv") {
            element.next().remove();
        }
    var msg = error.get(0).textContent;  
        error.insertAfter(element);
    },
```

I want to get error content after jquery.validate function triggered. In the errorPlacement of the code blog as you see above error.get(0).textContent can provide msg in every browser except ie 8, I think this cause from JSON parsing problem in ie8, do you have any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `error.text()` instead of `error.get(0).textContent`.

When you call `get(0)` jQuery returns a DOM element at 0th index and IE8 do not support `textContent` property to a DOM element it has `innerText` property which is equivalent to `textContent`.  If you call `text()` method on a jQuery object it will take care of cross browser issues and return the content correctly.

Comment: Thank you! thats work. But it is confusing that get json object value with just .text(),

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent

the "textContent" property is not supported in IE8 (only IE9+)